# Relationship between kernel function for distance (locally weighted regression) and kernel function for SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing

I am reading Tom Mitchell's Machine Learning. In section 8.2.3, he defines: Kernel function is the function of distance that is used to determine the weight of each training example. In other words, the kernel function is the function $K$ such that $w_i = K(d(x_i, x_q))$.
However, when we talk about SVMs we have a kernel function $K(x,y) = \phi(x) \cdot \phi(y)$. Is kernel function (when talking about locally weighted regression or maybe k-NN) just a totally different thing from kernel function (SVMs)?

Comment: Unfortunately, many authors in ML community are too liberal with their use of terminology. Some, like Kevin Murphy in Chapter 14 of his ML book, bother to mention that the term _kernel_ means different things depending on the context. In particular, he distinguishes a _Mercer kernel_, which by definition is symmetric and induces a positive semidefinite Gram matrix (Mercer's theorem says you always have a corresponding $\phi(\cdot)$, possibly infinitely dimensional). In contrast, weights arising in the Nadaraya-Watson model (also called "kernels" sometimes) are not even symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two kinds of kernel functions are just distinct concepts. They do have related intuitions as similarity functions, but any connections beyond that are (to may knowledge) not particularly thorough.